# $4$ women, $3$ men sitting at a round table

Tags: combinatorics

I always get confused with combination questions that involve round tables?
If there were $4$ women and $3$ men sitting at a round table with no restrictions, how many possible combinations would there be if we just looked at the people's genders

For example **'WWMWMMW'** would count as one seating even though the $4$ women can rearrange themselves in many ways in those $4$ women spots.

Comment: Do you distinguish between constellations which differ by a cyclic permutation?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Did you see that there are already quite a number of questions on the "placing people around a table" problem? It would be very helpful for you to read them and to explain in your question what it is that you still do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

If the chairs would have a number then the answer would be $\binom73=35=\binom74$. You just pick out $3$ numbered chairs for the men (or $4$ for the women if you like).

If the chairs are not numbered then each distinct arrangement will be counted $7$ times by the method above. This because e.g. choice $123$ is in that case actually the same as $234$,$345$,...,$671$,$712$.

So in that case there are $\frac17\binom73=5$ essentially distinct arrangements.

Be cautious, though. Luckily $7$ is a prime wich ensures that the overcounting is determined by factor $7$. This will not be so if $7$ is not a prime. If e.g. $2$ men and $2$ women must be have a seat then there are $2$ possibilities (the men sit next to each other or not), but $2\neq3=\frac12\binom42$.

Answer (score 0):

There are two groups so, 2 groups can be arranged in 1 way on table(Note the idea here, try to figure out that if they were sitting on line then ans would have 2! = 2 but for sitting on round line we subtract 1 & then calculate factorial)( Since on both the cases whether women group sits facing west or men group facing west, they both come to the left & right of each other), but if seated in group.
Now 3 men can be arranged in 3P3 ways i.e. 3! = 3X2 = 6 ways with each other
also Now 4 women can be arranged in 4P4 ways i.e. 4! = 4X3X2 = 24 ways with each other

if they are mixed with each other **on line** then 7P7 ways = 7! = 5040 ways

Now if they are sitting on round table then just subtract 1 & calculate factorial, So (7-1)! = **720 ways(ans)**

If you are trying to figure out how formula works then this will waste lots of time. So don't get confused & just subtract 1 before calculating normal permutation. That's it.